# When does GCC inserts a xor eax,eax?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I am searching for specific instructions in a binary file and, for the `xor eax,eax` instruction, i have a function like:

```
int foo(){
  return 0;
}
```

If i compile it with GCC 4.7.2  and -O2 or -O3 optimization flag, the assembly result of `foo()` is a nice

```
xor eax,eax
```

before exiting the function. Instead, if compiled with -O1 or even no optimization, the classical

```
mov eax,0x0
```

is produced.

The question is: is there any other way (in terms of C code and without __asm directives) to produce a

```
xor eax,eax
```

instruction with GCC and -O1 or no optimization set?

Comment: What is the *real* problem you have? Or is this just for the sake of curiosity?

Comment: This question is related to Return Oriented Programming. My goal is to find a xor eax,eax gadget with the smallest C code and O1 or no optimization set on GCC

Comment: @phant0m: XOR is preferred to MOV #0 in certain contexts because it is smaller and doesn't contain any NUL bytes, which allows it to be used in a string payload.

Answer (score 5):

The insn `xor %eax, %eax` is generated during the peephole optimization. Roughly speaking, peephole optimization pass walks the code looking for common patterns/idioms, which are known to perform better on the target CPU.

To answer you questions, you have to enable peephole optimization using `-fpeephole2`.

PS. `-fpeephole2` is enabled by `-O2`, but not by `-O1`.

Answer (score 0):

To get an `xor` instruction, you can use the xor operator:

```
register int i = 1;
i = i ^ i;
```

Ensuring that `i` uses `eax` may be more uncertain, though.

Comment: Wrapping in a function and returning `i` on the next line would probably give good odds for assignment to the `eax` register.

Comment: Unfortunately without -O2 or -O3 optimization this resulted in `mov eax,0x0` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to produce a `xor eax,eax` with a register in GCC without using a `-O2` or superior optimization (and without using the binary operation itself).

That's because `xor eax,eax` is equivalent to `mov eax,0`, but for some reason, GCC uses the xor method for optimization (I don't know which is faster). So if you want to generate an assembly code like this without any optimizations, you probably won't get it that easily, except for using the real xor operator in C/C++ (`^`).

Now if you use `-O2` and above, it's easy to get this kind of instruction, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

This will produce two `xor r1,r1` where `r1` is an arbitrary register, if compiled with `-O2`. The first xor instruction is in `a`'s initialization. And the second one is in the `return` value, which is 0, so it's making a `xor eax,eax`.

To test my example, you can use [GCC Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) with the `-O2` option.

Comment: `xor eax,eax` is faster (or, on older processors, at least as fast but taking fewer bytes). I'm rather surprised GCC likes `mov eax,0` so much.

Comment: The `xor reg, reg` is the method Intel recommends for zeroing a register. The reason is that these insns are recognized special cases in the register rename unit and are not passed for execution.Check section 2.1.3.1 of http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html

Comment: Also note that `xor eax,eax` is not equivalent to `mov eax,0` in all cases, because the former modifies flags while the latter doesn't. For example, a sequence like `mov eax,0; sub ecx,1; jne loopstart` could be optimised into `sub ecx,1; mov eax,0; jne loopstart` or `xor eax,eax; sub ecx,1; jne loopstart` but not `sub ecx,1; xor eax,eax; jne loopstart`.

Comment: @Brendan That's true, I just meant equivalent to what value the register would get, and in terms of mathematical theory...